# Implementing a C programm for logic gates circuit solution

Tags: c, logic, nor

Logic Gates circuit solution

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 10

int myand(int a, int b);
int myor(int a, int b);
int mynand(int a, int b);
int mynor(int a, int b);
int myxor(int a, int b);
typedef int (*CallBack)(int a, int b);
int getinput();


typedef struct function {
    CallBack f;
    char ch[10];
} MyFunction;

typedef struct gate {
    CallBack f;
    struct gate * in1 ;
    struct gate * in2 ; 
    
} Gate;

Gate * creategate(CallBack f);

int eval(Gate *x);


int main() {
    Gate *a_ptr, *a1_ptr, *a2_ptr, *b_ptr, *b1_ptr, *b2_ptr, *c_ptr, *c1_ptr, *c2_ptr, *d_ptr, *e_ptr, *f_ptr;
    
    a_ptr = creategate(mynor);
    a1_ptr = creategate(getinput);
    a2_ptr = creategate(getinput);
    a_ptr->in1 = a1_ptr;
    a_ptr->in2 = a2_ptr;
    printf("First gate's output: %d\n", eval(a_ptr));
    
    b_ptr = creategate(myand);
    b1_ptr = creategate(getinput);
    b2_ptr = creategate(getinput);
    b_ptr->in1 = b1_ptr;
    b_ptr->in2 = b2_ptr;
    printf("Second gate's output: %d\n", eval(b_ptr));
    
    c_ptr = creategate(myor);
    c1_ptr = creategate(getinput);
    c2_ptr = creategate(getinput);
    c_ptr->in1 = c1_ptr;
    c_ptr->in2 = c2_ptr;
    printf("Third gate's output: %d\n", eval(c_ptr));
    
    d_ptr = creategate(mynand);
    d_ptr->in1 = a_ptr;
    d_ptr->in2 = b_ptr;
    printf("Fourth gate's output: %d\n", eval(d_ptr));
    
    e_ptr = creategate(myxor);
    e_ptr->in1 = b_ptr;
    e_ptr->in2 = c_ptr;
    printf("Fifth gate's output: %d\n", eval(e_ptr));
    
    f_ptr = creategate(myor);
    f_ptr->in1 = d_ptr;
    f_ptr->in2 = e_ptr;
    printf("Circuit's output: %d\n", eval(f_ptr));
    

    free(a_ptr);
    free(a1_ptr);
    free(a2_ptr);
    free(b_ptr);
    free(b1_ptr);
    free(b2_ptr);
    free(c_ptr);
    free(c1_ptr);
    free(c2_ptr);
    free(d_ptr);
    free(e_ptr);
    free(f_ptr);
    
    return 0;
}


int myand (int a, int b) {
    return a * b;
}
int myor (int a, int b) {
    return a + b>0;
}
int mynand (int a, int b) {
    int result = a * b;
    if (result == 0) {
        result = 1;
    }
    else {
        result = 0;
    }
    return result;
}
int mynor(int a, int b) {
    int result = a + b>0;
    if (result == 0) {
        result = 1;
    }
    else {
        result = 0;
    }
    return result;
}
int myxor(int a, int b) {
    int a1=0, b1=0;
    if (a==0) {
        a1=1;
    }
    else if (a==1) {
        a1=0;
    }
    
    if (b==0) {
        b1=1;
    }
    else if (b==1) {
        b1=0;
    }
    return ((a*b1) + (a1*b))>0;
}

int getinput() {
    int x;
    printf("Enter input(0 or 1): ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    return x;
}

Gate * creategate(CallBack f) {
    Gate * temp ;
    temp = malloc(sizeof (Gate));
    temp->f = f;
    temp->in1 = NULL;
    temp->in2 = NULL;
    return temp;
}

int eval(Gate *x) {
    int a, b;
    if (x->in1 != NULL) {
        a = eval(x->in1);
    }
    if (x->in2 != NULL) {
        b = eval(x->in2);
    }
    if (x->in1==NULL && x->in2 == NULL) {
        return (x->f)(0,0);
    }
    else {
        return (x->f)(a,b);
    }

}
```

I first make the user enter each gate inputs using the getinput function.
After entering the first six inputs in the first three gates,
i want the programm to take automatically the outputs from the previous gates
without the user having to enter something. I tried many ways but i couldnt find
a solution. I need to keep the dynamic memory allocation and also all the structures
and i can add another function if necessary.

Comment: I think you need to consider what `eval` does in each and every case within. Remember: both `a` and `b` are indeterminate unless assigned by those `a = ...` and `b = ...` lines respectively. That's important, especially in the case where only *one* of them was assigned. I think you'd be *possibly* closer if `eval` initialized `a` and `b` to zero (i.e. `int a=0,b=0;` then did your two tests for `x->in1` and `x->in2` as you have them to overwrite `a` and/or `b`, throw out the third if-test+block entirely and just hard return your else body, but without the else.

Comment: Just noticing: You can swap 0 and 1 much more easily by simply having `result = !result`, but you can actually get the desired value directly if you adjust the comparison already: `a + b == 0` – and `xor` you can much more easily by `a != b`. Sure, breaks if one of is not 0 or 1, if you want to be robust against you could instead have `(a == 0) != (b == 0)`, assuming you want to consider any value unequal zero as 'true'...

Comment: The *'outputs'* from the previous gates? Don't you mean the *'inputs'*? I would assume you want to use the same inputs for the operation and the respective negated operation – is this correct? Then the main problem with your code is that all you have is operations, but these are entirely *stateless*. You will have to extend your entire design such that you can store a state as well. Once you've done that you wouldn't call `createGate` for the negated operations, but provide them the same stateful gates you provided to the non-negated operations.

Comment: By the way, as is you would not need to create multiple `getinput` gates, you could provide all the calculating gates (twice) with the one and only really necessary instance (stateless anyway, remember?) – changes, of course as soon as you do add states ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua i want the outputs from the gates to work as inputs to the next gates... i dont know if you get me... for example i have three gates each takes two inputs. the first is "and gate" and i give it 0 and 1. it returns 0. the second is an "or gate" and i give it 0 and 0. it returns 0. now i want to use the two outputs, i mean 0 and 0, as inputs to the last gate

Comment: Does the output of a given gate _only_ go to the input of a _single_ gate? If so, you can add `struct gate *out` to your gate struct. Also, you'll need an `int idx;` to indicate whether `out` is connected to `in1` or `in2` of the next gate (i.e. `out`). Otherwise, you'll need a more complicated way to connect them.

Comment: @CraigEstey it doesnt go as input to only one gate so can you guide me a bit more

Comment: Well, then again the same: You need *stateful* gates! You need to be able by some means to *store* the previous result. You could add another `int` to your `gate` struct, then you would need to store the value there somehow. You could change `eval` such that it would calcualate the value as long as there's no storage, otherwise return the stored value. Either use a separate variable remembering if storage took place or use a sentinel value (e.g. initialise to -1 on creation to indicate 'nothing yet stored'). Then you could set up the operands for subsequent gates with the existing ones.

Comment: @CraigEstey explain me a bit more how i can adjust what yoy said to my programm

Comment: Okay, I misspoke. You do _not_ want: `struct gate *out;` in the struct. But, as Aconcagua said, you want an `int out;`. Then, it's how you connect them. You want to change your logic functions (e.g.): `void myand(struct gate *gate) { gate->out = gate->in1->out & gate->in2->out; }` You'll need to organize them in a tree that matches the way you connect the gates.

Comment: Then, you want the equivalent of a depth first search. Except that when you visit a node (i.e. a gate), you call its function to set its output.

Comment: corect my code where necessary and send it if you can please

Answer (score 1):

A number of issues ...

1. There is no current [output] "state" in a gate struct.
2. The "operator" functions (e.g. `myand`, `myor`, etc.) return a value instead of setting the output value into the struct.
3. So, if a gate were connected to *multiple* outputs, the gate state would be evaluated *multiple* times (vs once per round).
4. The ordering of the gate levels is hardwired into the code (in the `eval` function).
5. The operator functions can be greatly simplified using C logic operators.
6. We can dynamically determine the order of evaluation of gates by assigning all gates at the same depth to a different list (i.e. separate list for each logic depth)
7. For clarity, I added names of the gates and functions to the gate struct.

---

Here is the refactored code. It is annotated. Unfortunately, I had to rewrite most of it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>

#define SIZE 10

struct gate;
typedef void (*CallBack)(struct gate *);

typedef struct function {
    CallBack f;
    char ch[10];
} MyFunction;

typedef struct gate {
    const char *sym;                    // gate name

    CallBack f;                         // operation function
    const char *fsym;                   // name of operation

    int depth;                          // gate's logic depth
    struct gate *next;                  // peer gate at same logic level

    int out;                            // output state/value
    struct gate *in1;                   // input gate
    struct gate *in2;                   // input gate
} Gate;

// list of gates
typedef struct {
    Gate *head;
} List;

#define CREATE(_sym,_fnc) \
    Gate *_sym = creategate(#_sym,_fnc,#_fnc)

#define MAXDEPTH    100
int bottom_depth;                       // last/maximum depth
List levels[MAXDEPTH];                  // list of gates at a given depth

// leveladd -- add gate to given gate list
void
leveladd(List *list,Gate *add)
{

    Gate *prev = NULL;
    for (Gate *tmp = list->head;  tmp != NULL;  tmp = tmp->next)
        prev = tmp;

    if (prev != NULL)
        prev->next = add;
    else
        list->head = add;

    add->next = NULL;
}

// leveldel -- remove gate from given list
void
leveldel(List *list,Gate *del)
{

    Gate *prev = NULL;
    Gate *cur = list->head;
    for (;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next) {
        if (cur == del)
            break;
        prev = cur;
    }

    if (cur == NULL) {
        printf("leveldel: no match -- %s\n",del->sym);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (prev != NULL)
        prev->next = del->next;
    else
        list->head = del->next;

    del->next = NULL;
}

// gatevalue -- current output value of gate
int
gatevalue(Gate *gate)
{

    return gate->out;
}

void
myand(Gate *gate)
{
    int in1 = gatevalue(gate->in1);
    int in2 = gatevalue(gate->in2);

    gate->out = (in1 & in2) != 0;
}

void
myor(Gate *gate)
{
    int in1 = gatevalue(gate->in1);
    int in2 = gatevalue(gate->in2);

    gate->out = (in1 | in2) != 0;
}

void
mynand(Gate *gate)
{
    int in1 = gatevalue(gate->in1);
    int in2 = gatevalue(gate->in2);

    gate->out = (in1 & in2) != 0;
    gate->out = ! gate->out;
}

void
mynor(Gate *gate)
{
    int in1 = gatevalue(gate->in1);
    int in2 = gatevalue(gate->in2);

    gate->out = (in1 | in2) != 0;
    gate->out = ! gate->out;
}

void
myxor(Gate *gate)
{
    int in1 = gatevalue(gate->in1);
    int in2 = gatevalue(gate->in2);

    gate->out = (in1 ^ in2) != 0;
}

void
getinput(Gate *cur)
{
    int x;

    printf("Enter input(0 or 1) for gate '%s': ",cur->sym);
    fflush(stdout);

    char buf[10];
    fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin);

    // echo input if coming from redirected file (e.g.) ./myprogram < inp
    struct termios tio;
    if (tcgetattr(fileno(stdin),&tio) < 0)
        fputs(buf,stdout);

    x = atoi(buf);

    cur->out = x & 1;
}

// creategate -- create a new gate
Gate *
creategate(const char *sym,CallBack f,const char *fsym)
{
    Gate *cur;

    cur = calloc(1,sizeof(Gate));

    // name of this gate
    cur->sym = sym;

    // save the operator function
    cur->f = f;
    cur->fsym = fsym;

    // assume initial depth
    leveladd(&levels[0],cur);

    return cur;
}

// redepth -- [recursively] assign new depth to logic gate
void
redepth(Gate *cur,int newdepth)
{

    if (cur == NULL)
        return;

    if (newdepth > cur->depth)
        cur->depth = newdepth;

    ++newdepth;
    redepth(cur->in1,newdepth);
    redepth(cur->in2,newdepth);
}

// attach -- attach input gates to given gate
void
attach(Gate *a,Gate *b,Gate *c)
{

    a->in1 = b;
    redepth(b,a->depth + 1);

    a->in2 = c;
    redepth(c,a->depth + 1);
}

// gatename -- get name of gate
const char *
gatename(Gate *cur)
{

    if (cur != NULL)
        return cur->sym;

    return NULL;
}

// showgate -- show gate and children
void
showgate(Gate *cur)
{

    printf("  %s -- %s %s %s (DEPTH: %d)",
        cur->sym,gatename(cur->in1),cur->fsym,gatename(cur->in2),cur->depth);
}

// showlevel -- show all gates at given logic level
void
showlevel(List *list)
{

    printf("showlevel: %zu\n",list - levels);
    for (Gate *cur = list->head;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next) {
        showgate(cur);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

// showall -- show all logic levels
void
showall(const char *who)
{
    List *list;

    printf("showall: %s\n",who);

    for (list = &levels[0];  list < &levels[MAXDEPTH];  ++list) {
        if (list->head != NULL)
            showlevel(list);
    }
}

// moveall -- move gates to their correct logic level lists
void
moveall(void)
{
    List *old = &levels[0];

    Gate *next;
    for (Gate *cur = old->head;  cur != NULL;  cur = next) {
        next = cur->next;

        if (cur->depth != 0) {
            leveldel(old,cur);
            leveladd(&levels[cur->depth],cur);
        }

        // remember maximum depth
        if (cur->depth > bottom_depth)
            bottom_depth = cur->depth;
    }
}

// eval -- evaluate gate's new value
void
eval(Gate *cur)
{

    printf("\n");
    printf("eval:");
    showgate(cur);
    printf("\n");

    cur->f(cur);
    printf("eval: out=%d\n",cur->out);
}

// doround -- compute values for all gates for single time period
void
doround(void)
{

    for (int curdepth = bottom_depth;  curdepth >= 0;  --curdepth) {
        List *list = &levels[curdepth];
        for (Gate *cur = list->head;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next)
            eval(cur);
    }
}

// showround -- compute values for all gates for single time period
void
showround(void)
{

    for (int curdepth = bottom_depth;  curdepth >= 0;  --curdepth) {
        List *list = &levels[curdepth];
        for (Gate *cur = list->head;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next)
            printf("showround: %s --> %d\n",gatename(cur),gatevalue(cur));
    }
}

int
main(void)
{

    CREATE(a_ptr,mynor);
    CREATE(a1_ptr,getinput);
    CREATE(a2_ptr,getinput);
    attach(a_ptr,a1_ptr,a2_ptr);

    CREATE(b_ptr,myand);
    CREATE(b1_ptr,getinput);
    CREATE(b2_ptr,getinput);
    attach(b_ptr,b1_ptr,b2_ptr);

    CREATE(c_ptr,myor);
    CREATE(c1_ptr,getinput);
    CREATE(c2_ptr,getinput);
    attach(c_ptr,c1_ptr,c2_ptr);

    CREATE(d_ptr,mynand);
    attach(d_ptr,a_ptr,b_ptr);

    CREATE(e_ptr,myxor);
    attach(e_ptr,b_ptr,c_ptr);

    CREATE(f_ptr,myor);
    attach(f_ptr,d_ptr,e_ptr);

    showall("postadd");

    showall("premove");
    moveall();
    showall("postmove");

    // we can loop here if we wish
    doround();
    showround();

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the sample input I used:

```
1
1
1
1
1
0
```

---

Here is the output:

```
showall: postadd
showlevel: 0
  a_ptr -- a1_ptr mynor a2_ptr (DEPTH: 2)
  a1_ptr -- (null) getinput (null) (DEPTH: 3)
  a2_ptr -- (null) getinput (null) (DEPTH: 3)
  b_ptr -- b1_ptr myand b2_ptr (DEPTH: 2)
  b1_ptr -- (null) getinput (null) (DEPTH: 3)
  b2_ptr -- (null) getinput (null) (DEPTH: 3)
  c_ptr -- c1_ptr myor c2_ptr (DEPTH: 2)
  c1_ptr -- (null) getinput (null) (DEPTH: 3)
  c2_ptr -- (null) getinput (null) (DEPTH: 3)
  d_ptr -- a_ptr mynand b_ptr (DEPTH: 1)
  e_ptr -- b_ptr myxor c_ptr (DEPTH: 1)
  f_ptr -- d_ptr myor e_ptr (DEPTH: 0)
showall: premove
showlevel: 0
  a_ptr -- a1_ptr mynor a2_ptr (DEPTH: 2)
  a1_ptr -- (null) getinput (null) (DEPTH: 3)
  a2_ptr -- (null) getinput (null) (DEPTH: 3)
  b_ptr -- b1_ptr myand b2_ptr (DEPTH: 2)
  b1_ptr -- (null) getinput (null) (DEPTH: 3)
  b2_ptr -- (null) getinput (null) (DEPTH: 3)
  c_ptr -- c1_ptr myor c2_ptr (DEPTH: 2)
  c1_ptr -- (null) getinput (null) (DEPTH: 3)
  c2_ptr -- (null) getinput (null) (DEPTH: 3)
  d_ptr -- a_ptr mynand b_ptr (DEPTH: 1)
  e_ptr -- b_ptr myxor c_ptr (DEPTH: 1)
  f_ptr -- d_ptr myor e_ptr (DEPTH: 0)
showall: postmove
showlevel: 0
  f_ptr -- d_ptr myor e_ptr (DEPTH: 0)
showlevel: 1
  d_ptr -- a_ptr mynand b_ptr (DEPTH: 1)
  e_ptr -- b_ptr myxor c_ptr (DEPTH: 1)
showlevel: 2
  a_ptr -- a1_ptr mynor a2_ptr (DEPTH: 2)
  b_ptr -- b1_ptr myand b2_ptr (DEPTH: 2)
  c_ptr -- c1_ptr myor c2_ptr (DEPTH: 2)
showlevel: 3
  a1_ptr -- (null) getinput (null) (DEPTH: 3)
  a2_ptr -- (null) getinput (null) (DEPTH: 3)
  b1_ptr -- (null) getinput (null) (DEPTH: 3)
  b2_ptr -- (null) getinput (null) (DEPTH: 3)
  c1_ptr -- (null) getinput (null) (DEPTH: 3)
  c2_ptr -- (null) getinput (null) (DEPTH: 3)

eval:  a1_ptr -- (null) getinput (null) (DEPTH: 3)
Enter input(0 or 1) for gate 'a1_ptr': 1
eval: out=1

eval:  a2_ptr -- (null) getinput (null) (DEPTH: 3)
Enter input(0 or 1) for gate 'a2_ptr': 1
eval: out=1

eval:  b1_ptr -- (null) getinput (null) (DEPTH: 3)
Enter input(0 or 1) for gate 'b1_ptr': 1
eval: out=1

eval:  b2_ptr -- (null) getinput (null) (DEPTH: 3)
Enter input(0 or 1) for gate 'b2_ptr': 1
eval: out=1

eval:  c1_ptr -- (null) getinput (null) (DEPTH: 3)
Enter input(0 or 1) for gate 'c1_ptr': 1
eval: out=1

eval:  c2_ptr -- (null) getinput (null) (DEPTH: 3)
Enter input(0 or 1) for gate 'c2_ptr': 0
eval: out=0

eval:  a_ptr -- a1_ptr mynor a2_ptr (DEPTH: 2)
eval: out=0

eval:  b_ptr -- b1_ptr myand b2_ptr (DEPTH: 2)
eval: out=1

eval:  c_ptr -- c1_ptr myor c2_ptr (DEPTH: 2)
eval: out=1

eval:  d_ptr -- a_ptr mynand b_ptr (DEPTH: 1)
eval: out=1

eval:  e_ptr -- b_ptr myxor c_ptr (DEPTH: 1)
eval: out=0

eval:  f_ptr -- d_ptr myor e_ptr (DEPTH: 0)
eval: out=1
showround: a1_ptr --> 1
showround: a2_ptr --> 1
showround: b1_ptr --> 1
showround: b2_ptr --> 1
showround: c1_ptr --> 1
showround: c2_ptr --> 0
showround: a_ptr --> 0
showround: b_ptr --> 1
showround: c_ptr --> 1
showround: d_ptr --> 1
showround: e_ptr --> 0
showround: f_ptr --> 1
```